# What are global fields?

Tags: c#

As far as I know, C#/Dot net does not have global fields. Then what is meant by global field in the image below:

[image]

This is from the [multi-threading link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/synchronizing-data-for-multithreading)

Comment: C# doesn't, but Visual Basic does. Variables can be declared at "module (or namespace) scope", outside of any procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that's for VB. The page is for VB and C#